# PhpExcel FILENAME character encoding

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, phpexcel

I'm using PHPExcel to write a html/xls/csv output, and everything is in UTF-8, so when the filename doesn't have any special non-English character everything seems fine (including the DATA itself which has special non-English characters).

However PHPExcel doesn't accept my filename with special characters, how is that?

```
<?php
$output = "MySpecialFileÁÉP.csv";
$output = mb_convert_encoding($fileName,'UTF-8'); //Just to make sure
$objWriter->save($output);
?>
```

Any idea? I read that PHPExcel used UTF-16LE encoding, but in the current documentation they clearly state that everything uses UTF-8. What am I missing? My version is 1.7.6 so its the latest.

Comment: Are you receiving an error? What do you mean by "doesn't accept"?

Comment: Yes, I get an exception which also shows the encoding problem, like: :  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Could not open file tmp/���' in \PHPExcel\Writer\HTML.php:166 Stack trace: #0

Comment: Does your operating system support UTF-8 characters in filenames? Will a filename containing standard ASCII characters be saved in tmp?

Comment: yeeah thanks it turned out Microsoft does not somehow, I just stick to ANSI filenames.

Comment: Incidentally, the latest version of PHPExcel is 1.7.7 (released a few weeks ago) rather than 1.7.6